# Generic issue imported in SonarQube doesn't appear in Sonarqube dashboard

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube in Jenkins on my .NET project

I start and stop the scanner with `dotnet sonarscanner begin …` and `dotnet sonarscanner end` before and after the build.
The reports are correctly uploaded to the Sonarqube server, and I can see all the issues and code smells.

I want to add some custom issues, and I create a json file as shown on this page : https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/analyzing-source-code/importing-external-issues/generic-issue-import-format/

But I can't make it appear in the Sonarqube server.

Here is what I tried :

First, I created a single json file with the issues for all the projects, and reference it with an absolute path :

```
$fileLocation = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "sonar-custom-issues.json"

dotnet sonarscanner begin /d:sonar.host.url="$sonar_host" /k:"$sonar_project_name" /d:sonar.login="xxx" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml /d:sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 /d:sonar.externalIssuesReportPaths="$fileLocation"
```

When I do this, nothing appear.

I also tried to make a json file by csproj project, so I just changed `/d:sonar.externalIssuesReportPaths=sonar-custom-issues.json`

And I save a `sonar-custom-issues.json` file on each project, in the same folder as the csproj.

Now, the `dotnet sonarscanner end` fails - with no error in the logs :just lot of "INFO" and these lines :

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the content of the json file :

```
{
    "issues": [{
        "primaryLocation": {
            "message": "Custom Issue Message",
            "filePath": "MyProject.csproj",
            "textRange": {
                "startLine": 1
            }
        },
        "type": "VULNERABILITY",
        "ruleId": "my-rule",
        "engineId": "my-engine",
        "severity": "CRITICAL"
    }]
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, and I can't find an answer in the documentation.

So what should I do to have the issues appear in SonarQube ?

What I'm still not sure :

- Should I create a single json file or a file per project ?
- Where are the json files supposed to be placed ?
- Is the `filePath` property supposed to be absolute or relative ? And if relative, relative to what ? (the execution folder / the project root / something else ?)

---

A few days later, I found why it doesn't appear in SonarQube :
The issues need to be linked to an existing file, or Sonarqube just discards them.

Here the filePath links to a `csproj` file, but the sonarscanner only sends the `cs` files to Sonarqube.
When I link an issue to a cs file, it's ok.
(with a single json file, and using absolute paths)

So my new question is : How can I ask the sonarscanner to also send the `csproj` files to Sonarqube server ?